# MediaTypes of CD/DVD in registry

Tags: windows, registry, media-type, cddvd

I need to determine the type of disc is CD-R, CD-RW, DVD-R, DVD-RW, ...
I have found a registry key to view information about them:

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CD Burning\Drives\Volume{%GUID%}\Current Media`

In this key, it have a DWORD value `Media Type`.
I think based on ths value ​​I can classify disc types. But I can't find any documentation that mentions them. Currently, I can only try with CD-R, CD-RW, DVD-RW and find out what their values ​​are:

| Type | Value |
| --- | --- |
| CD-R | 0x02 (2) |
| CD-RW | 0x04 (4) |
| DVD-RW | 0x40 (64) |

Does anyone know anything about this `Media Type`, and what documentation mentions it?